# laravel 4.2.4 multiple users types

Tags: laravel-4

we have some groups of users (students teachers parents) with different property and they need different user tables (and they cant store in one users table with group id) (for example student users have parent_id classnumber and .. but teachers dont have)
but laravel default auth system provide one table users ....

i search for  multiple users types in laravel and find these:

- [Multiple user types in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531494/multiple-user-types-in-laravel-4)
- http://laravel.io/forum/02-15-2014-multiple-user-types-with-different-tables-for-each-group

but i cant solve the problem.

Please say a solution for laravel 4.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

What about using standard laravel users table as base, so you could store information laravel needs in it, as well as f.e. user_type_id, user_id - which will contain the information about user type and user id in the specyfic, separate tables with whatever fields you will need

Comment: is this the best solution? and dont exist any right way?